# Should it be event.join_user(user) or user.join_event(event)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, api-design

I have User model and Event model.
User can participate in events and i am not sure where to write the code - in UsersController and User model, or in EventsController and Event model

```
UsersController
  def join_event
    current_user.join_event(Event.find(event_id))
  end
end
```

or

```
EventsController
  def add_user
    Event.find(event_id).add_user(current_user)
  end
```

end

What solution is better and better readable ( or maybe there are even better way )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should depend on how you are going to create event object. Which object is easily accessible while creating your event object.

1st scenario :

If there is an organizer(admin) of event and organizer can only invite user then in this case. Code should be in event controller. As you need to iterate through user object collection not single object.

2nd scenario :

If user can directly join any already created event/create own event that other can join then it should be in user controller.

Comment: and 1 more question. if i have EventsController#add_comment is it ok ? where should i put #delete_comment - it looks ugly in EventsController cause comment has it's own id and model. Probably i should move both of them to CommentsController ? But comment has link to event...

Comment: Both should be in comments controller and there default action to create and delete comment. That restful provided. To do that you can use nested routing where you can pass `event_id` via url. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html